# Ошибка докер-компоуз

Tags: python-3.x, база-данных, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Возникла такая проблема, пытаюсь запустить сайт через докер компоуз, выдаёт такую ошибку. Ошибка возникает при заходе на локалхост, попытке сделать миграции и создать суперпользователь. Пробовал очищать контейнеры, volumes, images - результата не дало. Ниже прикрепляю саму ошибку, докер компоуз и настройки базы данных.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
web_1    |     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
web_1    |     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 141, in __call__
web_1    |     response = self.get_response(request)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 75, in get_response
web_1    |     response = self._middleware_chain(request)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
web_1    |     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
web_1    |     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 129, in handle_uncaught_exception
web_1    |     return callback(request, **param_dict)
web_1    |   File "/code/foodgram/views.py", line 10, in server_error
web_1    |     return render(request, 'misc/500.html', status=500)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
web_1    |     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
web_1    |     return template.render(context, request)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
web_1    |     return self.template.render(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
web_1    |     return self._render(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
web_1    |     return self.nodelist.render(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
web_1    |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
web_1    |     return self.render(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
web_1    |     return compiled_parent._render(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
web_1    |     return self.nodelist.render(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
web_1    |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
web_1    |     return self.render(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
web_1    |     return template.render(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 173, in render
web_1    |     return self._render(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
web_1    |     return self.nodelist.render(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
web_1    |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
web_1    |     return self.render(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 302, in render
web_1    |     match = condition.eval(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 876, in eval
web_1    |     return self.value.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 671, in resolve
web_1    |     obj = self.var.resolve(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 796, in resolve
web_1    |     value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
web_1    |     current = current[bit]
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 256, in inner
web_1    |     self._setup()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 392, in _setup
web_1    |     self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 24, in <lambda>
web_1    |     request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 12, in get_user
web_1    |     request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 182, in get_user
web_1    |     user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 59, in _get_user_session_key
web_1    |     return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 54, in __getitem__
web_1    |     return self._session[key]
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 194, in _get_session
web_1    |     self._session_cache = self.load()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 43, in load
web_1    |     s = self._get_session_from_db()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 32, in _get_session_from_db
web_1    |     return self.model.objects.get(
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
web_1    |     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 402, in get
web_1    |     num = len(clone)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __len__
web_1    |     self._fetch_all()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
web_1    |     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
web_1    |     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1095, in execute_sql
web_1    |     cursor = self.connection.cursor()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
web_1    |     return self._cursor()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
web_1    |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
web_1    |     self.connect()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
web_1    |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
web_1    |     self.connect()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
web_1    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
web_1    |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
web_1    |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1    |      Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web_1    |      TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1    | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1    |      Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1    |      TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

---

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  web:
    image: bdcry/foodgram:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/code/static/
      - media:/code/media
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.0
    volumes:
      - media:/code/media
      - static_volume:/code/static/
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
```

---

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '0906',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: В `settings.py` `HOST` должен быть `db` (т.е. как имя сервиса в `docker-compose.yml`), а не `localhost`.

Comment: к сожалению, это не сработало :( 
поменял название на db - такая же ошибка.

Comment: а вы логи базы смотрели, она вообще работает?

Comment: вторая, довольно частая проблема, это что постргрес еще не успел стартануть, когда зависимый контейнер уже пробует к нему присоединиться. читайте https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: И обновите вопрос, если поменяли `localhost`. С localhost точно работать не будет.

Comment: проблему решил, что-то занимало порт 5432, локально.